# Xpath is invalid in dojo library

Tags: jakarta-ee, dojo

I was implementing a demo web project in java using dojo as UI purpose.Continuously "xpath is invalid" error is coming and also its takes quite a long time for the IDE(eclipse) to build the project.I tried to solve it but the error remain the same.i will be grateful to any suggestion that could solve my problem.Also why IDE is taking so time to build it(i guess it's because of dojo library).I am using 1.9 version of dojo

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="&SupportedElements;"> //Error in this line"Xpath invalid token"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328051

In eclipse, exclude dojox/gfx/resources/svg2gfx.xsl from XSL validation.

Window -> Preferences;  Validation -> XSL Validator -> Settings;
Add exclude group, Add fule, choose the file